# from Xcel Vba select a range of text from one Word document and copy into another Word document

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to this: Please Help!

I saw the following code from one of the answers (thanks to those who provided it). The code works in Word VBA, I tested it.

```
Sub RevisedFindIt()
' Purpose: display the text between (but not including)
' the words "Title" and "Address" if they both appear.
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim strTheText As String

    Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
    If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Title") Then
        Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
        If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="Address") Then
            strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
            MsgBox strTheText
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to run the same code from EXCEL VBA, by calling it as a sub from a main excel vba sub and passing some arguments to it, as I need to use the data within EXCEL. My attempt below failed with a Compiler error:

> Argument not optional

in relation to the `.Find.Execute(FindText:=`.

```
Sub FindIt(ftext, text1, text2, texto)
' Purpose: display the text between (but not including)
' the words "Title" and "Address" if they both appear.

    'Dim wdDoc As Object, wdApp As Object

    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    'Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(ftext)
    wdApp.Visible = True

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim strTheText As String

With wdDoc

    Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
    If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:=text1) Then
        Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
        If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:=text2) Then
            strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
            MsgBox strTheText
            texto = strTheText
        End If
    End If

End With

wdDoc.Close savechanges:=False
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing

Set wdApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

Comment: Argument not optional means just that. You have omitted some arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Argument not optional means just that. You have omitted some arguments.
Use Intellisense: Type rng1.Find(
... and you will se the arguments
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually the .Find command worked in a Word vba sub. All I was trying to do is to make the same sub work in Excel.